# Echo Canceller Android API level 10

Tags: java, android, audio, echo-cancellation

I'm building an android audio app that has to support the API level 10 and I have Larsen effect problems. My android app streams the audio to a java app that outputs the sound.

I found the AcousticEchoCanceller of android but it is only available from the API level 16.

Is there a way to do that without this class ?
Or could I do it on the java app ?

Thank's

Lukas

Comment: What does the Java app run on? The echo canceller on the phone will be tuned based on using the phone's microphone and speaker.

Comment: The java app runs on a laptop computer.